# Error : Unable to use host type networking with links

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am new to the Docker World.I have got my db and server connected. Now i want to connect my frontend with server. I an unable to use network mode with link. Without using network mode, i am unable to view my frontend site on localhost:8080.
How can i connect my front and server?

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  front:
    build: ../Devops/operations-portal
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:8080:8080"
    network_mode: "host"
    volumes:
      - ../Devops/operations-portal
    links:
     - server

  server:
    build: ../Devops/data-mining-backend
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ../Devops/data-mining-backend/:/app
    links:
      - db

  db:
    image: mongo:3.6.5
    ports:
       - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - '../database:/data/db'
    command: mongod --smallfiles --logpath=/dev/null # --quiet
```

Comment: In port mapping you have added IP address. Is it of your local machine? First thing in port mapping there we can expose port only. And your docker container is separate environment from your local machine so you cannot access IP with 127.0.0.1

Comment: I removed that ip and just kept it as 8080:8080, still it is not working

Comment: Have you created image for front end?